# Time evolution of a tripartite quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, time-evolution, open-quantum-systems

Question:

How do we write the unitary evolution of a tripartite system in Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B \otimes \mathcal{H}_C$ when it is subject to two unitary evolution operators $U_{AB}$ and $U_{BC}$. $U_{AB}$ a unitary operator in $\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B$ acting on the $A$ and $B$ subsystems, and $U_{BC}$ is a unitary operator in $\mathcal{H}_B \otimes \mathcal{H}_C$, acting on the $B$ and $C$ susbsystems?

More details:

If a density operator $\rho_A$ exists in Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_A$ and undergoes unitary evolution, this can be written

$$\rho_A(t) = U_A(t)\rho_A(0)U_A(t)^\dagger$$

where $U_A(t)$ is a unitary operator in $\mathcal{H}_A$. Similarly, for a density operator in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_B$, we can write the evolution as

$$\rho_B(t) = U_B(t)\rho_B(0)U_B(t)^\dagger$$

where $U_B$ is a unitary operator in $\mathcal{H}_{B}$.

If we the consider the joint Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_A \otimes \mathcal{H}_B $, with $U_A$ acting only on the $A$ subsystem and $U_B$ acting only on the $B$ subsystem, we can write the evolution of the joint state as

$$\rho_{AB}(t) = U_{AB}(t)( \rho_A(0) \otimes\rho_B(0)) U_{AB}^\dagger(t) $$

where $U_{AB} = U_{A}\otimes U_B$. In this case, there was a simple way of writing the joint evolution operator $U_{AB}$, in terms of the unitary evolutions of the subsystems. My question is whether there is also a simple way of writing the joint evolution operator in the tripartite system described at the start.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I think that simply writing $U_{ABC} = U_{AB}\otimes U_{BC}$ is not the correct answer, as it would give an operator of the wrong dimension. Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: You have to fix the *order* in which you apply the unitary operators!

Comment: I would say you need to know what the Hamiltonian is. You only have one Schroedinger equation and only one evolution operator. So the problem does not exist to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are applying two consecutive evolutions on $B$, you have to decide which one to apply first. You have two possibilities, either

$$ U_{ABC}=(U_{AB}\otimes \mathbb 1_C)(\mathbb 1_A\otimes U_{BC})$$
or
$$ U'_{ABC}=(\mathbb 1_A\otimes U_{BC})(U_{AB}\otimes \mathbb 1_C).$$

In general, $U'_{ABC}\neq  U_{ABC}$.

It is actually the same in the bipartite case, where you have

$$ U_{AB}=(U_A\otimes \mathbb 1_B)(\mathbb 1_A\otimes U_B)$$
only in this case the two terms commute and you can simply write

$$ U_{AB}=U_A\otimes U_B.$$